# Search all numeric string and divide

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a `Output.txt` file which has following content:

```
Server1
APPNAME  MEMORY
WINDOWS  54896378
LINUX    78542
MACOS    187963

Server2
APPNAME     MEMORY
DATABASE    587412369
SCHEMA      78542
TABLESPACE  187963
```

I want to create a batch script which searches for all numeric values in Output.txt (like 54896378,78542,78542 etc.) and divide them by 1024*1024 sothat in Newoutput.txt file memory in BYTES can change into MB.

I tried below but not getting what I want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims= " %%a in ('findstr "[1-9][0-9]* 0"' Output.txt) do (
SET /A Result = %a / 1024*1024 > Newoutput.txt
)
```

**EDIT1**:

When `Output.txt` file has following content then everything is working fine but Script is not converting `FreePhysicalMemory` value 6621212 only i.e.:

**Output.txt:**

```
Server1
APPNAME  MEMORY
WINDOWS  54896378
LINUX    78542
MACOS    187963

FreePhysicalMemory  TotalVisibleMemorySize  
6621212                 8387172
```

**Newoutput.txt:**

```
Server1
APPNAME  MEMORY
WINDOWS  13.58
LINUX    2.45
MACOS    1.8

FreePhysicalMemory  TotalVisibleMemorySize  
6621212                 21.4
```

What changes we need to make in script..?

Comment: you do not write anything into your new file in the first place. Also you don't do anything with the Result you have obtained.

Comment: Batch math tops out at 2^31 -1 so you can't handle 2GB values or higher with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do note that batch only works with integers. Several of your calculations would result in a value of 0 MBs.  Here is a **rough example** of how to work with decimal values.

```
@echo off
call :Parse > Newoutput.txt
exit /b 0

:Parse
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (Output.txt) do call :ToMB "%%~B" "%%~A" || echo(%%A %%B
exit /b 0

:IsNumber <String>
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%A in ("%~1") do exit /b 1
exit /b 0

:ToMB <String> <Name>
setlocal
call :IsNumber "%~1" || exit /b 1
set "Number=%~1"
set /a "Number/=1024"
set /a "Decimal=Number"
set /a "Number/=1024"
set /a "Decimal-=(Number * 1024)"
set /a "Decimal=(Decimal * 1000) / 1024"
set "Decimal=000%Decimal%"
set "Number=   %Number%"
set "Name=%~2            "
echo %Name:~0,12%%Number:~-3%.%Decimal:~-3%
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

---

- Update: Added the AppName to the output along with *some* formatting. (Above)
- Update: Added Newoutput.txt redirect example. (Above)
- Update: Added conversion support for all tokens and improved formatting. (Below)
- Update: Added first line skip fix for the find command. (Below)

---

```
@echo off
call :Parse > Newoutput.txt
exit /b 0

:Parse
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('type "Output.txt" ^|find /n /v ""') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%X in ("%%~B") do call :Convert "%%~X" "%%~Y"
    call :Blank "%%~B"
)
endlocal
exit /b 0

:Blank <String>
set "String=%~1"
if not defined String echo.
exit /b 0

:IsNumber <String>
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%A in ("%~1") do exit /b 1
if "%~1"=="" exit /b 2
exit /b 0

:Convert <String> <String>
call :Calculate "%~1" Y || call :Display "%~1" Y
call :Calculate "%~2" || call :Display "%~2"
echo.
exit /b 0

:Calculate <Number> [Pad]
call :IsNumber "%~1" || exit /b 1
set "Number=%~1"
set /a "Number/=1024"
set /a "Decimal=Number"
set /a "Number/=1024"
set /a "Decimal-=(Number * 1024)"
set /a "Decimal=(Decimal * 1000) / 1024"
set "Decimal=000%Decimal%"
set "Number=000%Number%"
call :Display "%Number:~-3%.%Decimal:~-3%" %2
exit /b 0

:Display <String> [Pad]
set "String=%~1"
set "Pad=%~2"
if defined Pad set "String=%String%                        "
if defined String set /p "=%String:~0,24%" <nul
exit /b 0
```

---

- Update: Added PowerShell to Calculate routine to handle values up to 2^64 (Below)

---

```
:Calculate <Number> [Pad]
call :IsNumber "%~1" || exit /b 1
set "Number="
set "Decimal="
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%A in ('"PowerShell %~1 / ( 1024 * 1024 )"') do (
    set "Number=%%A"
    set "Decimal=%%B000"
)
call :Display "%Number%.%Decimal:~0,3%" %2
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Thanks.David..its working as a charm.:)..but APPNAME is not coming in output.

Comment: @Sunny  Glad to help, as for the APPNAME can you give an example of how you want it to display?  Like `APPNAME = 50 MB`?

Comment: @Sunny Updated with appname and other text.

Comment: Gr8..superbly working..i am trying to redirect the output to Newoutput.txt file..at which line i should put `> Newoutput.txt` ?

Comment: I put `> Newoutput.txt` at end of 2nd line..but redirection not working.

Comment: @Sunny put it at the script level `script.bat > Newoutput.txt` or on the `echo` line. `echo %Name:~0,12%%Number:~-3%.%Decimal:~-3% >> Newoutput.txt`

Comment: When i put it at echo line, i only get..
WINDOWS      52.352 

LINUX         0.074 

MACOS         0.178 

DATABASE    560.199 

SCHEMA        0.074 

TABLESPACE    0.178

formatting is also missed..i don't want another .bat just for redirection..:)

Comment: @Sunny Oops sorry, yeah the echo would not work.  I updated with a redirect example.

Comment: Hi David..m learning..!!:) Please see **EDIT1** in question..:)

Comment: @Sunny  Please, note as [foxidrive](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2299431/foxidrive) stated, the maximum value supported by batch is 2147483648.  As for FreePhysicalMemory not being converted, that is because it is in the first column and the script I wrote only converted numbers in the second column.

Comment: Thanks David..!:) Batch math has its own limitations..! :(

Comment: @Sunny  Yep, Batch has a many limitations.  I have updated my answer with a new example.

Comment: @David..all the three updates are working perfectly, but one point here has made me thinking: Why in all three update's output, the very first line is a blank ..!?

Comment: @Sunny  The first line is blank because the find command outputs an extra line at the beginning which was being stripped but still caused the `:Blank` routine to activate.  Run the `find /n /v "" Output.txt` command by itself and you will see what I am talking about.  I updated the example with a fix. `type "Output.txt" |`

Comment: @David..now everything is just Perfect..!!:)

Comment: @David...is there any solution in batch if values exceed 2 GB limit ?

Comment: @Sunny  I would recommend using PowerShell for values above 2GB.  Batch math is more work than the value.

Answer (score 3):

```
SET /A Result = %a / 1024*1024
```

This divides %a by 1024 and multiplies the output with 1024. This is not, what you want.
The correct division should be:

```
SET /A Result = %a / 1024 / 1024
```

Or you can precalculate 1024*1024 = 1048576 and

```
SET /A Result = %a / 1048576
```

Comment: Stephan..i modified and tried my code as per your suggestion..but don't know why its not working.