# Search and divide numeric strings

Tags: vbscript, jscript

I have an output.txt file which has following content:

```
Windows        6543765432
Linux          4534653463
MacOS          3564325
Ubuntu         8235646255
```

I want to create a VBScript which searches for all numeric values in output.txt  and divide them by 1024 so that memory in KB can be changed into MB.
I have tried in batch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428881/search-all-numeric-string-and-divide), but due to 2 GB limitation it's not working in above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top-level task is to modify a small file of structured text. The 'design pattern' for such a task is:

```
Get a FileSystemObject
Specify the full file path
Read the content
Modify the content
Write the modified content back
```

Your sub-task of modification involves computations on non-constant /varying parts; then a 'RegExp.Replace with Function' strategy should be used:

```
Define a RegExp (global, identify the parts to change)
.Replace(input, GetRef("function to do the computations on the parts"))
```

In your case, that function should convert the (string) parts to numbers, divide then, and return the result converted to strings.

In code:

```
  Option Explicit
  Const FSPEC = "..\testdata\txt\19556079.txt"
  Dim oFS : Set oFS  = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
  Dim sAll : sAll = Modify(oFS.OpenTextFile(FSPEC).ReadAll())
  oFS.CreateTextFile(FSPEC).Write sAll
  WScript.Echo oFS.OpenTextFile(FSPEC).ReadAll()

Function Modify(s)
  Dim re : Set re = New RegExp
  re.Global = True
  re.Pattern = "\d+"
  Modify = re.Replace(s, GetRef("FiMoReFunc"))
End Function

Function FiMoReFunc(sM, sP, sS)
  FiMoReFunc = CStr(CDbl(sM) / 1024)
End Function
```

For a more fancy output:

```
FiMoReFunc = Right(Space(20) & FormatNumber(CDbl(sM) / 1024, 1, True) & " Unit", 20)
```

output:

```
Windows            6,390,395.9 Unit
Linux              4,428,372.5 Unit
MacOS                  3,480.8 Unit
Ubuntu             8,042,623.3 Unit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Const FILE = "output.txt"
Dim fso
Dim ts,line
Dim match,matches
Dim os,mem

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(FILE)

With New RegExp
  .IgnoreCase = True
  While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    line = ts.ReadLine

    .Pattern = "[a-z]+"
    Set matches = .Execute(line)
    For Each match In matches
      os = match.Value
    Next

    .Pattern = "\d+"
    Set matches = .Execute(line)
    For Each match In matches
      mem = (CDbl(match.Value) / 1024)
    Next

    WScript.Echo os & vbTab & mem
  Wend
End With

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: -0.49 for not defining the RegExps out of the line loop and filtering os and mem to the last occurences in the match loop.

Comment: It works with the example data file given and hopefully demonstrates that RegExp is the key object here. The question author clearly has enough skill to dissect this into what he/she needs