# Division: overcoming 2 GB limitation of batch math

Tags: batch-file

I have a **output.txt** file which has following content:

```
Windows        6543765432
Linux          4534653463
MacOS          3564325
Ubuntu         8235646255
```

I want to create a batch script which searches for all numeric values in output.txt and divide them by 1024 (only integer part required in result not decimal places ) sothat memory in KB can be changed into MB (overcoming 2 GB limitation of batch math ) 
Trying with below but no output..

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=" %%a in (output.txt) do (
set /a MB=!b!/1024
echo %%a !MB!
))
```

Comment: does [this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/battech_math_chop_example.txt) help?

Comment: you can look into the workaround section of [this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php) too

Comment: set /a has a limitation for 32bit, gawk may help you on this, it has a windows/linux version.

Comment: I responded to your comment/question on your [previous post with a PowerShell option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19429961/891976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set JScall=Cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in (output.txt) do (
      for /f %%a in ('%JScall% "%%j/1024"') do set a=%%a
      for /f "delims=." %%z in ("!a!") do set a=%%z
      echo %%i     !a!>>newout.txt
   )
)
goto :EOF

@end
WScript.Echo(eval(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Item(0)));
```

try that?... `;)`

Comment: @Nephi..Error: **Invalid number.Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision**

Comment: The nubers you are using must already be too big... give me a sec.

Comment: You don't need two `for` commands: `for /f "delims=." %%a in ('%JScall% "%%j/1024"') do set a=%%a`, and your code have an additional non-needed right parentheses...

Comment: your point? . . . I like to put an extra parenthesis to catch missed ones, and I addressed the problem of the decimal separately for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with pure Batch splitting the number in two groups of 5 digits each, and operating each group accordingly:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (output.txt) do (
   call :KBtoMB %%b MB=
   echo %%a !MB!
))
goto :EOF

:KBtoMB KB MB=
set KB=%1
set KBhigh=%KB:~0,-5%
set KBlow=%KB:~-5%
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do if "!KBlow:~0,1!" equ "0" set KBlow=!KBlow:~1!
set /A %2=KBhigh/1024*100000 + (KBhigh%%1024*100000+KBlow)/1024
exit /B
```

As a matter of fact, you may divide a number with unlimited number of digits this way!

Answer (score 1):

gawk can be easily for any text hanlding from simple to complex

```
gawk " {printf(\"%s %d\n\", $1 ,$2/1024)}" output.txt
```

and it works fine under any OS include windows, linux.

```
C:\dos>gawk " {printf(\"%s %d\n\", $1 ,$2/1024)}" output.txt
Windows 6390395
Linux 4428372
MacOS 3480
Ubuntu 8042623
```

Comment: its working..! i really like using 'gawk'..but i am restricted to install it on windows server.

Comment: gawk.exe is just with a single binarny, if you have rights to write in the server, just need to copy, then everything is ok.